# Visual Studio 2013: How to combine properties from different forms in the same c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to copy a form from a c# project to another in the same VisualStudio  solution. I copied the form to the target project, but that form used some images from Properties.Resources in its original project and now it doesn't find that source.

How should I solve that problem? or is there an easier solution to copy one form to a new project?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can make a User control from form and share it between multiple projects

Comment: Add the resources to the second project.

Comment: When you add an image then you get a choice, you can store it in the project's resources or you can store in the form's resources.  Fifty-fifty odds to pick the option that would have made it easy to move the form :)